# Dynamics CRM - Custom development

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm completely new to the Dynamics CRM environment.

Within our current implementation, there is a grid which displays a list of current sales opportunities.   Within this grid, there is a column for the user which is a link to another part of Dynamics.  We want to instead be able to open a new window to another system.  How can I customize how that link gets rendered out so that the client "onclick" function can link to a javascript function which will open a new window with the URL we need?

Please see attached:
[Snapshot of Dynamics grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5UmU.png)

Comment: Way too broad.. another system url going to be dynamic? Try something on your own & post some specific problem

Answer (score 1):

I`m afraid that this is not possible with supported customization.
My understanding is that you will keep URL to external system on entity and you would like to be able to open with single click from grid displaying this record?
However, I`m not sure if you add this fields as single line of text with format option URL won`t work as expected. If this does not work, you would need a custom grid to display this data.

Answer (score 0):

You can store url in text field with format URL, click on such field will open link in new window/tab.

[image]